# Look like bug in suggested edit

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

"https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76533/getting-crazy-for-edi-tpl" i made an edit to this post, it show my name but not my edit and also not get any reputation. Looks like bug in suggested edit.

[image]

Comment: To support the "edit clash" suggestion made here, the [list of your suggested edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12418/bala?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) doesn't list the suggested edit you made for that post. That means that for the system, yours was just an edit to change the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't a bug - the only change you made was to add the [theme-templates](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-templates) tag. That change is currently showing so the edit went through fine.

As I understand it, once you have 500 reputation points, edits that consist of only re-tagging a post don't go into a review queue. So there's no reputation 'reward' for their acceptance.

Update

Looks like there was a clash with another edit at the same time. That would probably explain why your more substantial edit got lost.

Comment: hmmm i don't have any proof to show my edit made to that post and even it not shown in that suggested edit http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/76533/revisions

Comment: There's nothing under the [revision history](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/76533/revisions) except for the tag change. Are you absolutely positive you submitted more changes than that? Any chance you just made a mistake and thought you'd altered more than the tags but hadn't? Importantly - can you reproduce it again? If so we can escalate this to the main meta site. If not I fear it will be too localised an incident to investigate. I haven't seen any similar reports on meta.so or anything

Comment: Yes i made more changes to that post and also i can reproduce it.

Comment: OK, could you put the exact steps to reproduce the bug into the question please? Be as detailed as possible so the devs have a chance to reproduce it too

Comment: Clive, @Bala I'm pretty sure I reviewed edit by Bala, one that was more than just retag. Actually, they was damn similar to changes by develkar in edit #2.

Comment: i tried but no luck, because at that time of edit  @develkar also made the changes. see the edited time for both edits

Comment: Yeah they were about a minute apart. You mentioned you could reproduce it, could you edit the question and add the steps to do so in? Without that the devs aren't likely to look into it :)

Comment: Ok, i will edit the question. but what do you mean about the steps

Comment: As I see it (but we would need perfect timing to test it): If 2 people start to edit at about the same time, and >2k person saves after <2k one, when the <2k one is not yet accepted, it gets discarded. We would need a question to test it on.

Comment: @Mołot good catch. Bala, this is the expected behaviour: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118359/no-reputation-awarded-for-a-suggested-edit. Don't worry about updating the question I think this is simply a race condition that another editor 'won' on this occasion

Comment: @Mołot you are the only man to prove my situation, great thanks

Comment: Clive, update your answer maybe, then? @Bala sorry to hear rep missed you. You'll earn plenty soon, I'm sure. This is one of the technical limitations in Internet systems overall, that's cheaper to live with than to fight in non-critical systems like here.